# Spring boot & Angular application Deployement

Tags: angular, spring-boot, deployment

i need to create a .sh/.exe file which contains eclipse STS  commands to run the spring boot application and the same thing for angular with VS Code.. i don't know if there is other solutions.
My problem is how to create an executable file which run my project.
Any help please? 
Thank you.

Comment: To be clear. You want to run the application without running java -jar xy.jar Right?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli yess , i want an executable file which can run the application

Comment: On Windows do you need an exe or do you want to run the app as a windows service?

Comment: i need to run it with .exe file

Answer (score 1):

**Linux**

If you add the configuration executable=true to the maven plugin.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <executable>true</executable>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

This will add an extra script at the front of the file and make it executable on Linux.

See the documentation for more information: https://tryingthings.wordpress.com/2018/03/14/packaging-a-spring-boot-application-as-windows-exe/

**Windows**

Windows is not that straight forward. You could use Launch4J http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/

Here is a guide how to configure the Launch4J Maven plugin:

https://tryingthings.wordpress.com/2018/03/14/packaging-a-spring-boot-application-as-windows-exe/